# Prevent application from closing due to a 'connection refused' error

Tags: python, sockets

I am writing a Python client which connects with simple sockets in a server (also written in Python). I want to prevent client termination when the connection in server refused. In other words, I want to make client "search" for the server (if there is no connection) every 30 seconds.

Here is the code I wrote, but when the connection terminates from the server, the client returns an error for connection refused, and terminates itself.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket
import time

while True:

    sock = socket.socket()
    host = socket.gethostname()
    port = 4444
    conn = sock.connect((host,port))

    while(conn != None):
        print 'Waiting for the server'
        time.sleep(30)
        sock = socket.socket()
        host = socket.gethostname()
        port = 4444
        conn = sock.connect((host,port))

    while True:

        recv_buf = sock.recv(1024)

        if (recv_buf == 'exit'):
            break

        print(recv_buf)
        sock.send('hi server')
```

Error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "s_client.py", line 12, in
> ```
>
> conn = sock.connect((host,port))   File "C:\Program Files\python27\lib\socket.py", line 224, in meth
>       return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args) socket.error: [Errno 10061] ─ίΊ ▐ΪάΊ ϊΫΊάΪ▐ ύ ϊύΉώΎΫ±ή▀ά ≤²Ίϊί≤ύ≥,

So any idea, that will help not to terminate the client, but to make it continuously look for the server, is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `try`-`except`:

```
conn = None
while(conn == None):
    sock = socket.socket()
    host = socket.gethostname()
    port = 4444
    try:
        conn = sock.connect((host,port))
    except:
         print 'Waiting for the server'
         time.sleep(30)
```

It's better to avoid the initial `connect` call and perform the connect only through the `connect` in the `while` loop. I have made a few other changes too, like moving the `sleep` call to the `except` part.

Comment: The OP could also get rid of line 12, and just set conn=None outside this loop, which would be more elegant, would print "Waiting" each time (because you are waiting, each time) and would avoid duplicate try-except clauses.  As it stands, this answer will still terminate when the first connect fails.